# Get YouTube Channel Subscriptions in Java

Tags: java, api, youtube, youtube-api

I know that Google has an extensive API for YouTube, and I know that they have articles pertaining to the use of the API with Java, but I have had no luck finding out how to check statistics. I basically want access to everything I can access within the Analytics page of my YouTube control panel.

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but after browsing a little bit it looks like `YtStatistics` has `getViewCount`.  I have no idea if this is what you're looking for.  javadoc is [here](https://developers.google.com/gdata/javadoc/com/google/gdata/data/youtube/YtStatistics).

Comment: View Count is one thing that I do want. However, I also want to know the number of subscribers and, if possible, the amount of money the channel has made (ability to check anything from Analytics would be nice). I also have no idea how to connect to YouTube and get an instance of the `YtStatistics` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get those using [Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/)

[Sample requests](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/sample-requests) would help you understand.

Analytics API is a different service but libraries come in same package and you can use same authorization with adding "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly" scope

[Here's a JAVA sample](https://github.com/youtube/yt-samples-java/tree/master/youtube-analytics-cmdline-report-sample) for Analytics API./

Comment: Could you show me an example of how to use the Analytics API with Java?